# Get Original Dimension from a .xml file

Tags: android, android-xml

I've been tasked with getting an old .apk operational (no source code). I've been able to open the .apk in Android Studio and look at the files. While I'm fairly new to Android Studio I've been able to to start piecing things together to see what things needs to changed to make things work. Because I can't edit the files in the .apk, I have to re-write the files in a new project.

One of the issues I'm running into is how to get back to the original dimensions used in the .apk. When I look at the .arsc file, see entries like this dimension(4097) and dimension(256) for horiztonal_margin and vertical_Margin. Is there any way to find out what the original dimension were or am I stuck trying to guess and check.
Example from the code included below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/vertical_margin"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >
     
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="dimension(13569)"
            android:text="TextView"
             />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far as those numbers are concerned, they are the ones that are inside the `R` class in java and are generated during buildtime
So you will have to reverse map them by checking with the R class

Another approach to opening an `.apk` file directly, is using `apktool` or `jadx-gui` which is the more hacker and human friendly approach to reverse engineer the apk or in your terms inspect and get it operational

You can find [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and [jadx-gui](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) linked